# background process in bash script/vi

Tags: linux, bash, vi, openvpn

I have a question regarding adding a process to the background while in a bash script. I have a small script to test the speed of openvpn as if the server was a client. However openvpn likes to run in the foreground preventing any kind of extra commands to be run.

Normally just doing it through the cmd line, I run:

```
$ (openvpn --config myconfig.opvn) &
```

However in vi I try to do this and it doesn't work like it does on the cmd line.

```
connect () {
    (openvpn --config myconfig.opvn) &;
    sleep 30;
    $speed --server 2426 | grep 'Download\|Upload' > $log;
    killall openvpn;
}
```

Is there a way to do this in vi so that it works like i want it to?

Thank you.

Comment: what is the problem? How do you it does not work the you want?

Comment: Are you saying you run `connect()` from the command line, it doesn't work? You don't need the semicolons unless you have multiple commands on the same line.

Comment: Actually I think the line (openvpn --config myconfig.opvn) &; should yield a syntax error because the ';' is a command separator and sending the command background results in no command to execute before this semicolon (not sure about the justification). Without the semicolons, it should work as expected

Comment: @tod It connects to openvpn just fine. However it doesn't run in the background thus not allowing the speedtest_cli.py to run. It sits on the foreground not allow any other commands to be run without ctrl+c out of it.

Comment: @Emilien No syntax error at all nor should it give me one.

Comment: why not write your `connect` function to a file, and the `:! connect` from vi cmd-line. Good luck.

Comment: Then why this fails? I just put this line in a script and ran it `(openvpn --config myconfig.opvn) &;` I got `foo.sh: 2: foo.sh: Syntax error: ";" unexpected`. Moreover the vi tag is inaccurate.

Comment: You don't actually appear to be doing anything with vi other than editing a script. I suggest you remove the reference to vi in your title; you may get more help that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the **openvpn** in different file. lets say xyz.sh and call the xyz.sh from your connect function as shown below:

file : xyz.sh

> (openvpn --config myconfig.opvn)

```
connect () {
    . ./xyz.sh &
    sleep 30;
    $speed --server 2426 | grep 'Download\|Upload' > $log;
    killall openvpn;
}
```

**. ./xyz.sh** will open a new console and will run the **openvpn** command for you. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is some redundant syntax which may be getting in the way. Here is your code cleaned up a little.

```
connect () {
    openvpn --config myconfig.opvn &
    sleep 30
    $speed --server 2426 | grep 'Download\|Upload' > $log
    killall openvpn
}
```

Note that I removed the extraneous sub-shell around openvpn; though I would have thought that what you had would have worked.

Suggest running openvpn with a higher level of debug tracing.